# Does Multi Draggable feature supported in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, draggable, multi-select

Is there any directives availble AngularJS for the Multi Draggable capability. At least if i can get a lead would be good to start. There are lot of plugins available in jQuery, hoping there will be some components available in angularJS.

Thanks 
S